# Cant call multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a cart system with Ajax and a multidimensional session array. The array stores the product id and quantity of this id. I am trying to display the quantity of one of these stored id's but the right value is not returned.

Here is my php code

```
public function create()
    {
        session_start();
        $product_id = $_GET['data'];

        // Check if the cart has been created
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) AND $_SESSION['cart'] != NULL)
        {
            // One or more items are have already been placed in the cart
        }else{
            // The cart is empty
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
            $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = array('quantity' => 3);
        }

        // Return the quantity of a stored product id
        return $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['quantity'];
    }
```

As you can see the number 3 should be returned. Instead I get the value 1.

Comment: Maybe it's already set? And 1 is set?

Comment: What does `print_r($_SESSION['cart'])` output?

Comment: I can't use print_r since my response is returned with ajax :/

Comment: run a print_r and check the output in firebug or any other developer tool which are very much useful.

Comment: return $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id][0]['quantity'];

Comment: Return '<pre>'.$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['quantity'].'</pre>';

Comment: <pre> has the same result.

Comment: When I run print_r the ajax function keeps loading. No output is shown.

Comment: simple: run firebug and console in firebug, it will show all responses from ajax requests